# Test sidekiq running remotely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openshift, sidekiq

How can I test sidekiq running on remote server? I can start sidekiq:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec sidekiq
```

but I don't know if it work or not. I don't use capistrano, I can use only cron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this question makes a whole lot of sense.  Have you gotten it running on your local development machine?  If so, you should be able to do the same thing to test it remotely.  Set up a job for it to run in the background, then ssh into your gear and use top or ps -ef to see if the process runs.